# How to draw part of GeoJSON?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I load all geojson (countries) in `VectorSource` by url. It is displayed instantly on the map.

But I need to display specific part of geojson. For example user selects USA country and the map have to draw only USA borderies.

How to do that in OpenLayers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create new vector layer, and on select event add selected features from geojson file into new layer:

vectorCountires.getSource().clear();
vectorCountires.getSource().addFeatures(arrayOfFeatures);